# A cascaded regexp doesn't match when used with /g modifier

Tags: regex, perl

Let's consider this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = <<END_FILE;
*   Action    : Lorem ipsum
*               Dolor oktam
*               Lorem lorem
*
*   Input     : var1
*               var2
*               var3
*
*   Output    : var4
*               var5
*               var6
END_FILE


$_ = $file;

my ($action, $input) = ('', '');

if (/action\s+:\s*((.|\r\n|\n)*?)(\r\n|\n).*\s*input/gi) {
    say "Action: $1";
}

# Not capture anything
if (/input\s+:\s*((.|\r\n|\n)*?)(\r\n|\n).*\s*output/gi) {
    say "Input: $1";
}

# But this time it works
if ($file =~ /input\s+:\s*((.|\r\n|\n)*?)(\r\n|\n).*\s*output/gi) {
    say "Input OK: $1";
}

# And $_ isn't different from $file
die "WTF!" unless $_ eq $file;
```

I would like to extract information after "Action", "Input" and "Output". The bizarre thing happens when I try to get the information after "Input". If I use `$_` the regex doesn't match anything but it works if I use `$file` even though `$_ eq $file`

Where does my problem comes from?

The output I get is this:

```
Action: Lorem ipsum
*               Dolor oktam
*               Lorem lorem
*
Input OK: var1
*               var2
*               var3
*
```

Comment: Why would you want to assign `$_` to a var?

Comment: @fugu For a better readability. It avoids to always specify on which var I'm working on `$var =~ /foo/` simply become `/foo/`. In fact this example is taken from a bigger program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using `/g`, which will make the next match try to find a match after the end of the last match. Since the first match will consume `input`, the second will start after `input` and thus will never find another `input` to match.

You can remove `/g` to solve this.

[perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) will tell you that:

> The `/g` modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching
>   as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on
>   the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings
>   matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If
>   there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched
>   strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.
>
> In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match, returning
>   true if it matches, and false if there is no further match. The
>   position after the last match can be read or set using the `pos()`
>   function; see `pos`. A failed match normally resets the search position
>   to the beginning of the string, but you can avoid that by adding the
>   /c modifier (for example, `m//gc`). Modifying the target string also
>   resets the search position

Comment: Whooh! Very interesting information. I always thought regex modifiers have only a local scope. Is there any official documentation about this?

Comment: @coin, some doc can be found in perlop. Added it to the answer.